# How to configure jsoup whitelist to allow internal anchor

Tags: java, jsoup

How do I configure a jsoup `Whitelist` to allow internal anchor references, without allowing any arbitrary value?

Example html:

```html
<a href="#section1" target="_self">Jump To Section 1</a>
    <!-- ... -->
<a name="section1">Section 1</a>
```

If I attempt to clean the code with the relaxed `Whitelist` the `href` is removed.

```
Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed().addAttributes("a", "name", "target");
```

returns the following:

```html
<a target="_self">Jump To Section 1</a>
   <!-- ... -->
<a name="section1">Section 1</a>
```

If I manually build a `Whitelist` and add the tags and attributes that I want, but don't call `addProtocols(....)` I can get jsoup to leave the `href` in place, but that doesn't seem like a good solution as it doesn't filter out `href`'s that contain JavaScript. For example, I want the a tag (or at least the `href`) removed from the following:

```html
<a href="javascript:alert(1111);" target="_self">Jump To Section 1</a>
<a name="section1">Section 1</a>
```

Is this possible with jsoup?

I did see the following patch submission to jsoup, but it doesn't look like it made it into the jsoup code base:  https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/77

Answer (score 3):

```
Whitelist whitelist=new Whitelist();

Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(whitelist);

whitelist.addAttributes("a","accesskey","dir","lang","style","tabindex","title","href");

cleaner.clean(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

If no protocols are provided/whitelisted, then all of them are implicitly allowed (see [isSafeAttribute](https://github.com/rorygibson/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.java)).  If you want to allow internal anchors, then you need to never call `addProtocol` on your whitelist's anchor tags, unfortunately (well, on the `href` at least).  It looks like there was a [pull request](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/77) to add support, but it was never merged.

Be aware that if you are allowing all protocols, that a malicious user can run Javascript on link click:

`<a href="javascript:alert('Arbitrary code');">Some text</a>`

so be cautious of that if you do not trust your HTML.

If you want to only allow say, `http`, `https`, and anchor tags, then I believe you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The reply get 3 upvotes doesn't answer the question at all.

The github link mentioned in the OP is currently merged, and for others who  are looking  for the answer

```
Whitelist.relaxed().addProtocols("a", "href", "#")
```

[Reference: Jsoup API Document](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#addProtocols-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)